# Pairs trading intercept

Tags: pairs-trading, algorithm, allocation

For a pairs trade, when calculating the zscore should I include the intercept point in the calculation:

```
spread = price2 - (gradient * price1) - intercept
zscore = (spread - average)/standard_deviation
```

or should I exclude the intercept:

```
spread = price2 - (gradient * price1)
zscore = (spread - average)/standard_deviation
```

I then check the zscore and trade accordingly:

```
if zscore > 2.5:
  sell qty2
  buy qty2
elif zscore < -2.5:
  buy qty2
  sell qty1
```

Also, should the spread calculation include the gradient:

```
spread = price2 - (gradient * price1)
```

or

```
spread = price2 - price1
```

?

Comment: No it does not. This is a different but related question. Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference whether you include the intercept or not. When you calculate the Z-score you are subtracting the mean as your first step. If you "forgot" to subtract `intercept` in your definition of `spread` then it will be removed when subtract `mean`. You should be able verify this by running the calculation both ways and seeing that the answer is the same

Comment: Thanks Jamie for the answer I needed.